# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare sp_button_group_addon() (previously declared in

Tags: php, joomla

**PHP version: 7.4**

**The joomla template I bought is showing this error below I need help to correct it**

*ERROR*
Link https://voltshost.com.br/aarontrans/

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare sp_button_group_addon() (previously declared in /home/storage/f/7e/46/voltshost2/public_html/aarontrans/templates/transpro/sppagebuilder/addons/button_group/site.php:15) in /home/storage/f/7e/46/voltshost2/public_html/aarontrans/templates/transpro/sppagebuilder/addons/button_group12/site.php on line 15
```

**'Document CODE' Site.php**
This is a **TRANSPRO** template file
[https://themeforest.net/item/transpro-transport-trucking-logistics-joomla-template/18420654](TransPro By ThemeCanyon)

```
<?php
/**
 * @package SP Page Builder
 * @author JoomShaper http://www.joomshaper.com
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010 - 2016 JoomShaper
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPLv2 or later
*/
//no direct accees
defined ('_JEXEC') or die ('restricted aceess');

AddonParser::addAddon('sp_button_group','sp_button_group_addon');
AddonParser::addAddon('sp_button_group_item','sp_button_group_item_addon');

$sppbButtonGroup_margin = '';
function sp_button_group_addon($atts, $content){
    global $sppbButtonGroup_margin;

    extract(spAddonAtts(array(
        'alignment' =>'',
        'margin'    =>'',
        'class'     =>''
        ), $atts));

    $sppbButtonGroup_margin = $margin;

    $output  = '<div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-button-group ' . $alignment . ' ' . $class . '">';
    $output .= '<div class="sppb-addon-content" style="margin:-' . (int) $margin . 'px;">';

    $output .= AddonParser::spDoAddon($content);

    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    $sppbButtonGroup_margin = '';

    return $output; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**First of all; IMO it's a better approach to contact the developer you bought the template from.**

As your provided data, you have got a error for redeclaring a function called `sp_button_group_addon` in two files
`aarontrans/templates/transpro/sppagebuilder/addons/button_group/site.php` and `aarontrans/templates/transpro/sppagebuilder/addons/button_group12/site.php`

You can solve the error by checking if `function_exist` or `changing the name` of the function (in one of those file)

##### solution 1: change the function name

which i think is better because the function seems to be hooked

```
<?php
/**
 * @package SP Page Builder
 * @author JoomShaper http://www.joomshaper.com
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010 - 2016 JoomShaper
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPLv2 or later
*/
//no direct accees
defined ('_JEXEC') or die ('restricted aceess');

AddonParser::addAddon('sp_button_group','sp_button_group_addon_12');
AddonParser::addAddon('sp_button_group_item','sp_button_group_item_addon');

$sppbButtonGroup_margin = '';
function sp_button_group_addon_12($atts, $content){
    global $sppbButtonGroup_margin;

    extract(spAddonAtts(array(
        'alignment' =>'',
        'margin'    =>'',
        'class'     =>''
        ), $atts));

    $sppbButtonGroup_margin = $margin;

    $output  = '<div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-button-group ' . $alignment . ' ' . $class . '">';
    $output .= '<div class="sppb-addon-content" style="margin:-' . (int) $margin . 'px;">';

    $output .= AddonParser::spDoAddon($content);

    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    $sppbButtonGroup_margin = '';

    return $output; 
}
```

##### solution 2: check if the function already declared

check if the function in both files have the same content, then let's ignore one of them.

```php
<?php
/**
 * @package SP Page Builder
 * @author JoomShaper http://www.joomshaper.com
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010 - 2016 JoomShaper
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPLv2 or later
*/
//no direct accees
defined ('_JEXEC') or die ('restricted aceess');

AddonParser::addAddon('sp_button_group','sp_button_group_addon');
AddonParser::addAddon('sp_button_group_item','sp_button_group_item_addon');

$sppbButtonGroup_margin = '';
if( !function_exists('sp_button_group_addon') ){

    function sp_button_group_addon($atts, $content){
        global $sppbButtonGroup_margin;
    
        extract(spAddonAtts(array(
            'alignment' =>'',
            'margin'    =>'',
            'class'     =>''
            ), $atts));
    
        $sppbButtonGroup_margin = $margin;
    
        $output  = '<div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-button-group ' . $alignment . ' ' . $class . '">';
        $output .= '<div class="sppb-addon-content" style="margin:-' . (int) $margin . 'px;">';
    
        $output .= AddonParser::spDoAddon($content);
    
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
    
        $sppbButtonGroup_margin = '';
    
        return $output; 
    }
}
```